# Moving a infopath form from one site collection to another

Tags: infopath

I have problem with moving a infopath form from one site collection (dev computer) to another. WHat I did was to create a list and create an infopath form. Once the form was all ready and published, i exported the list using stsadm and the form was also exported as part of it.

Now, when I import the list on test, it gets imported fine. However, I get WARNING when i open ADD NEW ITEm as follows
    You do not have permissions to access a SharePoint list that contains data required for this form to function correctly.

The form calls sharepoint rest service (listdata.svc) as well. It also has a lookup field to another list (which has also been exported). THe form does save the item correctly, however. But, the warning message shows up anyway.

The strange thing is that the form was working before i made changes to it to include the rest service calls.

How can i fix this? Also, is there a way to publish an infopath form without infopath designer installed? Like, for example, using stsadm, powershell or any other command line tool or switches?

Thanks,
E

Answer (score 1):

In your case you have 2 major issues the way I see it:

1. Using listdata.svc and lookup lists it also means you are tight-up
   to the original site. The reason you get the warning is that most
   like moving from site collection to another you are also forcing the
   InfoPath to do an cross-domain jump . You would need to update the
   data sources, or even better I would recomand you export those Data
   Connections from the Form and use a Data Connections library which
   simply stores in an Xml file details about your connection source.
   As soon as you re-publish your form on another site you would update
   only Connections and you're all set.
2. About publishing the form - yes indeed there are other ways - such as "Administrator Published Form templates" - but that also means that you are no longer using the InfoPath as a simple Edit-form for a list, but as an Xml form - which is actually stored as a Document upon every save.